# Cannot output an array in C programming?

Tags: c

I cannot seem to output a string or an integer array correctly in C programming.

My issue, is that the strings are stored in the array, I just cannot get them OUT of the array and to the output.

When I manually enter the positions (like `Array[0]`), it properly outputs.

However, the final loop fails to output any of my array entries.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for all replies!

Here is the code:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main (void)
{
    int memory_start;
    int memory_end;
    int num_jobs;


    printf("Enter the starting memory location to be used : ");
    scanf("%d", &memory_start);

    printf("\nEnter the ending memory location to be used : ");
    scanf("%d", &memory_end);

    printf("\nHow many jobs will be assigned to the memory locations?  \n");
    scanf("%d", &num_jobs);

    int mem_size = memory_end - memory_start;
    int mem_size_init = memory_end - memory_start;
    char names[10][20];
    int  sizes[num_jobs];
    int  mem_st[10];
    int  mem_end[10];
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int temp_size = 0;
    int prev_temp_size;
    char temp_name[20];


    for(x=0; x<num_jobs; x++)
    {
        prev_temp_size = prev_temp_size + temp_size;
        printf("\nEnter the size of the program (size > 0): ");
        scanf("%d", &temp_size);

        if( mem_size >= temp_size && temp_size > 0)
        {
            printf("\nEnter a program name (20 chars): %s", names[1]);
            scanf("%s", &temp_name);

            if(strlen(temp_name) <= 20)
            {
                strcpy(names[x], temp_name);
            //  names[x] = temp_name;
                sizes[x] = temp_size;
                mem_size = mem_size - temp_size;
                mem_st[x] = prev_temp_size + memory_start;
                mem_end[x] = temp_size + mem_st[x];
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nProgram name is too long. Please re enter data.");
                x--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nMemory Size not supported (not enough space remaining).\nPlease re-enter data with a plausible memory request.");
            printf("\nMemory size remaining: %d", mem_size);
            x--;
        }
    }

    printf("\nYour data is as follows: \n");
    printf("\nYour initial memory size is: %d", mem_size_init);
    printf("\nYour unused memory size is: %d", mem_size);

    for(y=0; y<num_jobs; y++)
    {
        printf("Program: %s", names[y]);
        printf("\n", names[y], " memory size is as follows: \n", "memory start: %d", mem_st[y], "    memory end: %d", mem_end[y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post just the problematic part of the code instead of the entire code.

Comment: I don't suppose you realise that the very last line in your last loop only prints a single newline and nothing else.

Comment: This is not how a **format specifier** is prepared try replacing the last line with: `printf("\n%s memory size is as follows: \n memory start: %d memory end: %d", names[y], mem_st[y], mem_end[y]);` all variables need to be placed at the end after the single format specifier string.

Comment: Remove the `&` in `scanf("%s", &temp_name);` because the name of an array already returns a reference to its first element.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! I realized that the last loop was my problem area, but couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong! I have changed it and the mem_st and mem_end are finally working! I figured out the proper syntax for 2D string arrays and got that working now as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main (void)
{
 int memory_start;
 int memory_end;
 int num_jobs;

 printf("Enter the starting memory location to be used : ");
 scanf("%d", &memory_start);

 printf("\nEnter the ending memory location to be used : ");
 scanf("%d", &memory_end);

 printf("\nHow many jobs will be assigned to the memory locations? ");
 scanf("%d", &num_jobs);

 int mem_size = memory_end - memory_start;
 int mem_size_init = memory_end - memory_start;
 char names[10][20];
 int  sizes[num_jobs];
 int  mem_st[10];
 int  mem_end[10];
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
 int temp_size = 0;
 int prev_temp_size;
 char temp_name[20];

 for(x=0; x<num_jobs; x++)
 {
  prev_temp_size = prev_temp_size + temp_size;
  printf("\nEnter the size of the program (size > 0): ");
  scanf("%d", &temp_size);

  if( mem_size >= temp_size && temp_size > 0)
  {
   printf("\nEnter a program name (20 chars): ");
   scanf("%s", temp_name);
   getchar();

   if(strlen(temp_name) <= 20)
   {
    strcpy(names[x], temp_name);
    sizes[x] = temp_size;
    mem_size = mem_size - temp_size;
    mem_st[x] = prev_temp_size + memory_start;
    mem_end[x] = temp_size + mem_st[x];
   }
   else
   {
    printf("\nProgram name is too long. Please re enter data.");
    x--;
   }
  }
  else
  {
   printf("\nMemory Size not supported (not enough space remaining).\nPlease re-enter data with a plausible memory request.");
   printf("\nMemory size remaining: %d", mem_size);
   x--;
  }
 }

 printf("\nYour data is as follows: \n");
 printf("\nYour initial memory size is: %d", mem_size_init);
 printf("\nYour unused memory size is: %d\n", mem_size);

 for(y=0; y<num_jobs; y++)
 {
  printf("\nProgram: %s\n", names[y]);
  printf("\nmemory size is as follows:\nmemory start: %d memory end: %d\n", mem_st[y], mem_end[y]);
 }
}
```

Apart from changes in formatting the output, major changes are:

- Removed the `&` in `scanf("%s", &temp_name);` because, the name of an array already returns a reference to its first element.
- Added a `getchar();` after `scanf("%s", temp_name);` because after reading in a string an extra `\n` remains in the stream, which causes the next `scanf` to fail.
- This:

  ```
  printf("\n", names[y], " memory size is as follows: \n", "memory start: %d", mem_st[y], "    memory end: %d", mem_end[y]);
  ```

  is not how a format specifier is prepared, all variables need to be placed at the end, after a single format specifier string.

Comment: thanks for the input! truly appreciated! Everything is working great now. I did not realize that I needed to output like that. Figured it wasnt all that different from java haha.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).

Answer (score 0):

The last loop is the issue.

```
for(y=0; y<num_jobs; y++)
{
    printf("Program: %s", names[y]);
    printf("\n memory size is as follows: ");
    printf("\n memory start: %d  memory end: %d", mem_st[y], mem_end[y]);
}
```

In C, the variables are given at the end of the printf. Also you are printing `names` two times, which i guess you don't want.

Comment: appreciate it! I didn't realize the %'s connect to each array at the end. Yeah I was trying my hardest to test the code and figure out what was going on and that is how the first names got printed.